# Is it possible to redirect Console output of an attached application?

Tags: c#, console-application, io-redirection

I have a console app that redirects stdout to a file, like this:

```
private static void Main()
{
  Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter("redirect.txt") {AutoFlush = true});

  Console.Title = "MyConsoleApp";
  Console.Error.WriteLine("This goes from console app to console");
  Console.WriteLine("This goes from console app to file");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Works as expected, the console shows one line of text and the other one appears in the file.

I also have a second Winforms app that attaches to a console:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool AttachConsole(uint dwProcessId);

private void AttachAndWrite()
{
  IntPtr h = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "MyConsoleApp");
  uint p;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(h, out p);
  if(AttachConsole(p))
    Console.WriteLine("I want this go to redirect.txt, but it ends up in the console window.");
}
```

The output of Console.Writeline now goes to the Console window, and not to the file as I would have expected.

1. Why?
2. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Have you considered using `Trace.WriteLine` instead? Then you can use a `TraceListener`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx

Comment: @Flynn Yes, generally I'm using [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/). I'm just curious how Console.WriteLine works with an attached console, and why it does what it does right now.